# HTTP Status 404 - Requested Resource Is Not Available

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ejb

I am working on a small EJB application..I have a JSP page with a form where user fill its details and on button click it is being send to a servlet page where the data is to be added through my entity class.But when I click on the button on JSP page, I am getting the following error

HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

descriptionThe requested resource () is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2

My servlet page Contactservlet.java is

```
 public class Contactservlet extends HttpServlet {
@EJB
private AbstractFacade cfl;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try 
    {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String mail=request.getParameter("mail");
        String phn=request.getParameter("phn");
        String cmnt=request.getParameter("cmnt");
        Contact c=new Contact();
        c.setCmnt(cmnt);
        c.setMail(mail);
        c.setName(name);
        c.setPhn(phn);
        cfl.create(c);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

My web.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Contactserv</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Contactservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Contactserv</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Contactserv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Code for my JSP file is

```
<form action="Contactservlet">
        Name <input type="text" name="name"/>
        Mail <input type="text" name="mail"/>
        Phone <input type="text" name="phn"/>
        Comment <input type="text" name="cmnt"/>
        <input type="submit" name="bt" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your JSP file is wrong, and if you posted the part of it that "calls" the servlet, then someone would tell you how you wrongfully set the button's target.

Comment: This is my Jsp file <form action="Contactservlet">
            Name <input type="text" name="name"/>
            Mail <input type="text" name="mail"/>
            Phone <input type="text" name="phn"/>
            Comment <input type="text" name="cmnt"/>
            <input type="submit" name="bt" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

Comment: @Isaac I have posted my JSP page for your convinience..Now can u tell my where I am wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has to do with incorrect setting of the form's `action` attribute. You need to set it dynamically, factoring in your web application's context root:

```
action="${request.contextPath}/Contactserv"
```

(By the way: your current JSP has "/Contactservlet" in it. The action must specify the `servlet-mapping` of the servlet you'd like to refer to)

A better way would be to use JSTL:

```
action="<c:url value="/Contactserv"/>"
```

Comment: I tried this but the result is still the same